# Symfony locale in URL via JMSI18nRoutingBundle

Tags: php, symfony, security, internationalization

I'm using Symfony 3.3 in conjunction with the [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle).

The bundle puts the user-locale in front of the routes. This works fine, untill I have to login or logout, these DO NOT work.

I always get the following error:

```
Unable to find the controller for path "/en/admin/logout". The route is wrongly configured.
```

This is part of my security.yml covering the login/logout:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
        anonymous: ~
        pattern: ^.*/admin
        form_login:
            login_path: /{_locale}/admin/login
            check_path: /{_locale}/admin/login
            [...]
        logout:
            path: /{_locale}/admin/logout
            target: /{_locale}/admin/login


access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

For the login_path, check_path, etc. I've also tried instead of {_locale}, .*, and just a slash (/) but none of these work.

The admin-logout is configured in my routing.yml:

```
admin-logout:
    path: /admin/logout
```

This gets rendered in twig properly, when using path('admin-logout'), I get a URL with the locale in it, but when I click it, it just displays the above error message again.
Login also doesn't work, I can however display the login page, but after entering credentials, it just refreshes the page without having logged in.

Anyone have any idea how to get the login/logout working again?

---

**EDIT:**

Thanks to nifr I could solve it, I should've used the route name, not the path in the security.yml, this is what I ended up with:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
        anonymous: ~
        pattern: admin
        form_login:
            login_path: admin-login
            check_path: admin-login
        [...]
        logout:
            path: admin-logout
            target: admin-login

     [...]
```

I did not change anything in my routing.yml, as the JMSI18nRoutingBundle already puts the locale placeholder in front of the route (if you do put {_locale} there, you end up with routes like: /en/en/admin/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`login_path` and `check_path` don't support placeholders when using **paths** (i.e. `/xy/{z}` ).

You need to use the **route's names** plus define a default value for any placeholder.

> The login_path and check_path can also be route names (but cannot have
>   mandatory wildcards - e.g. /login/{foo} where foo has no default
>   value).

(Symfony Documentation - [How to Build a Traditional Login Form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html))

The following route definition and security configuration example would work:

```
# routing.yml
login_route_name:
  path:      /{_locale}/login
  defaults:
    _locale: 'en'
    _controller: app.controller_service.security:login
login_check_route_name:
  path:      /{_locale}/login/check
  defaults:
    _locale: 'en'
    _controller: app.controller_service.security:loginCheck

# security.yml
security:
  firewalls:
    firewall_name:
      # [..]
      form_login:
        login_path: login_route_name
        check_path: login_check_route_name
```

When using JMSi18nBundle you can find the names of your login/check routes using the `debug:router` command. For example:

```
bin/console debug:router | grep -i login
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was what I needed. 

I didn't change anything in my routing.yml, but used the route names in my security.yml (as you suggested), this was all that was needed